# JPA/Hibernate Unidirectional OneToMany as 'mappedBy'

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I recently found such mapping in our repo:

```
@Entity
...
public class Foo{
     ...
     @OneToMany(mappedBy = "someField", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
     public Set<Bar> bars;
     ...
}

@Entity
@IdClass(Bar.Key.class)
...
public class Bar{
     @Id
     public long someField;
     @Id
     public long anotherField;
     ...
     static class Key implements Serializable {
        public long someField;
        public long anotherField;
     }
}
```

There are no foreign keys in both tables.
I was surprised that there is no `@ManyToOne` field in the `Bar` class and `@OneToMany` is annotated without `@JoinColumn` as `mappedBy`. Anyway it works perfectly: without redundant updates - like it's a bidirectional mapping. I'm not an expert in JPA/Hibernate and I've never seen such mapping in tutorials/guides/docs. I tried to google such mapping but I didn't find any explanation. Is it OK to map entities like this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bidirectional one-to-many and both many-to-one association mappings are fine. But you **should avoid unidirectional** one-to-many associations in your domain model. Otherwise, Hibernate might create unexpected tables and **execute more SQL statements than you expected**.

The definition of an unidirectional one-to-many association doesn’t seem to be an issue. You just need an attribute that maps the association and a @OneToMany relationship.

Reference [see ref](https://thoughts-on-java.org/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/)

Comment: @MS90 The question is " Is it OK to map entities like this ?"  The Answer is  " you should avoid because it execute more SQL statements than you expected".

Comment: Can you elaborate what addditional SQL statements( the one aside needed ) are executed? @Khalid Shah

Comment: @MS90 i also provide a link for this. you can read example from there :)

Comment: Take a look at Use orphanRemoval when modeling parent-child associations section of that article. @Khalid Shah. I gave +1 for nice link.